# I am unable to set an email alias in an Azure Runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, azure-managed-identity

I have a need to create email aliases for exchange accounts. I am attempting to do this with an Azure Automation Runbook.

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -ManagedIdentity -Organization "myorg.onmicrosoft.com" 

# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$name = $Request.Query.Name
if (-not $name) {
    $name = $Request.Body.Name
}

$user = $Request.Query.User
if (-not $user) {
    $user = $Request.Body.User
}

Get-Mailbox -Identity $name | Format-List  

#Set-Mailbox $user -EmailAddresses @{add="{"+$name+"@myorg.com"}
```

Get-Mailbox is working but set-mailbox is failing with Failed (Unauthorized).

I have a managed service account with Exchange online permissions. Which I know is working because Get-Mailbox is working.

Does anyone know what permissions need to be set on this to allow this from set-mailbox Azure powershell in this scenario?

Comment: Says only available with Premise Exchange : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-mailbox?view=exchange-ps#-linkedcredential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this figured out.

For reference:
Go to https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/AllRolesBlade

Search for "Exchange Receipt Administrator"

Assign it to your managed identity

This allows the managed identity to create the alias.